# Submultiplicative Matrix norm and regularity of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, inverse

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider a submultiplicative matrix norm $\| \cdot \|$. Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $A$ is invertible. Assume that
>
> $$\|B-A\| < \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.$$
>
> Show that $B$ is invertible.

I do not know what I could do to prove that. Could you give me a hint? Does it have something to do with eigenvalues or the spectral theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\|A^{-1}B - I\| = \|A^{-1}(B-A)\| \leq \|A\|^{-1}\cdot \|B-A\| < 1.
$$
From there, one approach is to consider the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$.